# How do edit animated GIF image with GD?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I use this function to update an animated GIF image, but GD is rendering it as static?

```
function draw_image ()

  {

    $img=imagecreatefromgif('images/moni.gif');

    $text='test';
    $lastpayout='test'; 
    $colors['name'] = imagecolorallocate($img, 999, 000, 156);
    ImageTTFText($img, 9, 0, 20, 235, $colors['name'], "images/impact.ttf", $text);
    ImageTTFText($img, 9, 0, 20, 250, $colors['name'],"images/tahoma.ttf",$lastpayout);
    ImageTTFText($img, 10, 0, 15, 270, $colors['name'], "images/tahoma.ttf", $text);
    header("Content-type: image/gif");
    imagegif($img);
  }

echo  draw_image ();
```

This function converts the animated GIF into a static GIF. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [*When reading animated GIF files into memory, only the first frame is returned in the image resource pointer*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)

Comment: I don't now if it's related to your problem but `imagecolorallocate` uses RGB values of 0-255.

Comment: I think OP is referring to "static" as the first frame from the GIF, not white-noise

Comment: i use this function for load gif : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php / but steel not work .

Comment: what errors do you get? what does not work?

Comment: nothing only render gif is static and not animate :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use [imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php):

```
$gif = new Imagick('full/path/to/your/image.gif');

$draw = new ImagickDraw();    
$draw->setFont('full/path/to/your/font.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize(30);
$draw->setFillColor('white');

// put text on each frame
foreach($gif as $frame){
  $gif->annotateImage($draw, $x = 10, $y = 45, $angle = 0, 'Your text');         
}    

header('Content-Type: image/gif');
print $gif->getImagesBlob();
```

Comment: You will need to install the imagick PHP extension. On most Linux distributions should be easy: `apt-get install php5-imagick`

Answer (score 1):

GD doesn't support animated GIFs. You can try imagick.

Comment: it does: `Note:

GIF support was removed from the GD library in Version 1.6, and added back in Version 2.0.28. This function is not available between these versions.`

Comment: @Robin key word is *animated*